# How to stretch an element to fill the space between two elements having fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to place an `<img>` with known width and height to the left, a `<div>` with known width and height to the right, and a `<div>` that will fill up the width in between the above `<img>` and `<div>` and flexibly stretch in height depending on the content. How can I achieve this **without Javascript**?

Comment: try to set "display:inline-block" or "float:left" to all the three elements

Comment: Flexbox concept also helps you to achieve this. Help link - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Who'd vote to close this as *primary opinion based*..!, Oh wait... now I saw the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need flexbox for this. You can position the `<img>` and `<div>` left and right by applying respective `float` value and stretch the middle `<div>` by applying position `absolute` and giving `left`and `right` values equal to the width of the element at the respective side.

Regarding the height, unless explicitly specified, absolute positioned elements shrink wrap to fit their content by default so you don't have to worry about it:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: hotpink;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
#flexible {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px; /*width of image*/
  right: 100px; /*width of div*/
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<img id="left" class="fixed" src="http://cdn-media-2.lifehack.org/wp-content/files/2014/10/widescreen-adam-levine-background-1024x640.jpg" />
<div id="flexible">Some Content</div>
<div id="right" class="fixed"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexBox model to archieve this, this is a css3 module soported by all modern browser and some old browser with polyfill.

this is an example of this.

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

}

.fixedWidth {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;  
   margin-right: 20px
}

.flexibleDiv {
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    width: 80%;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1; 
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2y1c5deL/

This is a Flexbox polyfill

https://github.com/doctyper/flexie